# Get single sprite from sprite atlas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, textures, sprite

I'd like to get a single sprite which GameObject has in a SpriteRenderer component.
Unfortunately, this code returns the whole atlas, but I need to a part of this atlas.

```
Texture2D thumbnail = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.texture;
```

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native API to get single sprite from the `SpriteRenderer` and no API to access individual Sprite by name. You can vote for this feature [here](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/allow-access-to-sprite-packer-atlas-to-retrieve-sprites-by-name).

You can make your own API to get single sprite from Atlas located in the `Resources` folder like the image included in your question.

You can load all the sprites from the Atlas with `Resources.LoadAll` then store them in a dictionary.A simple function can then be used to access each `sprite` with the provided name.

A simple Atlas Loader script:

```
public class AtlasLoader
{
    public Dictionary<string, Sprite> spriteDic = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();

    //Creates new Instance only, Manually call the loadSprite function later on 
    public AtlasLoader()
    {

    }

    //Creates new Instance and Loads the provided sprites
    public AtlasLoader(string spriteBaseName)
    {
        loadSprite(spriteBaseName);
    }

    //Loads the provided sprites
    public void loadSprite(string spriteBaseName)
    {
        Sprite[] allSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(spriteBaseName);
        if (allSprites == null || allSprites.Length <= 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("The Provided Base-Atlas Sprite `" + spriteBaseName + "` does not exist!");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < allSprites.Length; i++)
        {
            spriteDic.Add(allSprites[i].name, allSprites[i]);
        }
    }

    //Get the provided atlas from the loaded sprites
    public Sprite getAtlas(string atlasName)
    {
        Sprite tempSprite;

        if (!spriteDic.TryGetValue(atlasName, out tempSprite))
        {
            Debug.LogError("The Provided atlas `" + atlasName + "` does not exist!");
            return null;
        }
        return tempSprite;
    }

    //Returns number of sprites in the Atlas
    public int atlasCount()
    {
        return spriteDic.Count;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

[image]

With the Example image above, "*tile*" is the base image and *ball*, *bottom*, *people*, and *wallframe* are the sprites in the atlas.

```
void Start()
{
    AtlasLoader atlasLoader = new AtlasLoader("tiles");

    Debug.Log("Atlas Count: " + atlasLoader.atlasCount());

    Sprite ball = atlasLoader.getAtlas("ball");
    Sprite bottom = atlasLoader.getAtlas("bottom");
    Sprite people = atlasLoader.getAtlas("people");
    Sprite wallframe = atlasLoader.getAtlas("wallframe");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could put the image you need in the Resources folder by itself, then use the Resources.Load("spriteName") to get it. If you want to get it as a sprite, you would do the following:

```
Sprite thumbnail = Resources.Load("spriteName", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

Source: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-change-sprite-image-from-script.212307/

Answer (score -3):

Well with the new Unity versions you can do it easily using SpriteAtlas class and GetSprite method:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.html

So if you are working with the Resources folder you can do:

```
Resources.Load<SpriteAtlas>("AtlasName")
```

Comment: No, this does not work. Note that the sprite in this question is a Single Sprite that was cut into pieces using Unity's Sprite Editor. This solution does not work just like Håvard Nygård 's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315125/3785314).