# Unity: Memory overflow on Android Device by 800 GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, out-of-memory, gameobject

I want to try to show many GameObjects on one Screen. If I preload 777 Monsters (Prefab (included Text and a Image), I get "out of memory"-Exception on Android Device.

How can I handle this or do it better? I am new in Unity.

Can anyone tell me why i have about 14k Objects in Unity-Profiler? See screenshot below:

[image: Profiler screenshot]

Load monsters:

```cs
GlobalGameVars.monsterImages = new List<Sprite>(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Monsters"));
```

My Code:

```cs
public class MonsterPreviewManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject monsterPreviewPrefab;

    void Start()
    {
        LoadAllMonsters();
    }

    public void LoadAllMonsters()
    {
        List<Sprite> allMonsterImages = GlobalGameVars.monsterImages;

        if (allMonsterImages == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        GameObject newMonsterPreviewPrefab;

        foreach (Sprite sprite in allMonsterImages)
        {
            newMonsterPreviewPrefab = (GameObject)Instantiate(monsterPreviewPrefab, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainContent").transform);

            MonsterPreview monsterPreview = newMonsterPreviewPrefab.GetComponent<MonsterPreview>();

            Image monsterImage = monsterPreview.monsterImage;

            monsterPreview.monsterName.text = sprite.name;

            var tempColor = monsterImage.color;
            tempColor.a = 1f;

            monsterImage.color = tempColor;
            monsterImage.overrideSprite = sprite;

            newMonsterPreviewPrefab.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}

public class MonsterPreview : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image monsterImage;
    public Text monsterName;


    void Start()
    {
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Exception (ADB Debug)

```
05-10 10:18:04.438  2037  2134 D Unity   : Unloading 884 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
05-10 10:18:04.486  2037  2052 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 40.446615 ms
05-10 10:18:04.521  2037  2052 D Unity   : System memory in use before: 30.3 MB.
05-10 10:18:04.530  2037  2052 D Unity   : System memory in use after: 30.4 MB.
05-10 10:18:04.530  2037  2052 D Unity   : 
05-10 10:18:04.530  2037  2052 D Unity   : Unloading 3 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2259.
05-10 10:18:04.530  2037  2052 D Unity   : Total: 9.076693 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.649769 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.361231 ms MarkObjects: 8.016384 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.046615 ms)
05-10 10:18:04.530  2037  2052 D Unity   : 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : Trying to allocate: 8388609B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: Texture
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : Allocation happened at: Line:77 in ./Runtime/Utilities/dynamic_array.h
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : Memory overview
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 23943538B | peak: 36890011B | reserved: 25201090B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_1_FRAME ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_2_FRAMES ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_4_FRAMES ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 13631488B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_ASYNC ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_GAMEOBJECT ] used: 2880842B | peak: 2880914B | reserved: 3274637B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 571814937B | peak: 580203611B | reserved: 571851576B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 1586772B | peak: 1591092B | reserved: 1650303B 
05-10 10:18:06.975  2037  2052 D Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 323064B | peak: 0B | reserved: 3768320B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : Could not allocate memory: System out of memory!
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : Trying to allocate: 8388609B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: Texture
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : Allocation happened at: Line:77 in ./Runtime/Utilities/dynamic_array.h
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : Memory overview
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 23943538B | peak: 36890011B | reserved: 25201090B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_1_FRAME ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_2_FRAMES ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_4_FRAMES ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 13631488B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_ASYNC ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_GAMEOBJECT ] used: 2880842B | peak: 2880914B | reserved: 3274637B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 571814937B | peak: 580203611B | reserved: 571851576B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_PROFILER ] used: 1586772B | peak: 1591092B | reserved: 1650303B 
05-10 10:18:07.116  2037  2052 E Unity   : [ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 323064B | peak: 0B | reserved: 3768320B
```

Comment: 777 monsters on a mobile game? that sounds a lot.

Comment: @BugFinder I dont know. All Images are together under 40mb. If i dont render the image in the GameObject, i get the same Error.

Comment: Whats the Length of "allMonsterImages"?

Comment: @S.Fragkos Its `Debug.Log(allMonsterImages.Count);` -> `777`

Comment: @Bellkadse for start can you try to load the first 752 resources and tell me if u had an exception or it was loaded correctly?

Comment: @S.Fragkos Maybe i fix that but i am not happy with that. `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();`. I dont know why he load unused assets.

Comment: you should try to remove the texture on your prefab, then dynamically instantiate only one texture on your code and then apply this texture to all your monster. By this way, you should have only one texture and not 777.
You can set one texture to multiple gameobject with Renderer.sharedMaterial

Comment: I dont know if i understand you correctly. I have 777 images of monsters and all as sprites but how can i one image for all without using a very large sprite. All Image are PNG (Texture Type: Sprite (2D and UI))

I dont know what its better. Now i change my code a little bit and i dont use `UnloadUnusedAssets` anymore. 

`monsterImage.sprite = sprite;`instead of  `monsterImage.overrideSprite = sprite;`

In my Opinion, its very tricky to handle that.

Comment: @Bellkadse Sorry i didn't have been notified of your comment. @ me next time please.
You have 777 differents images? or it's only one image affected to 777 objects?
By the way, if you are on first case, did you try to use a Sprite Atlas?

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme I have 777 different images, but i can do a Sprite Atlas too. If i do that how can i assign these Sprite Atlas randomly to my monster object (image).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Sprite Atlas. Also, i see that your sprites are on a static variable, which is not a good idea, it can cause some memory leaks and show wrong sprite. It already happened to me.

You asked me in comment how assign these Sprite Atlas randomly to monster object. You should use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313398/get-single-sprite-from-sprite-atlas) to get a single sprite. Then, you probably will have to rename your monster like "monster-1", ... "monster-777", and then write something like:

```
void Start()
{
  AtlasLoader atlasLoader = new AtlasLoader("monsters");
  for(int i = 1; i <= atlasLoader.atlasCount(); i++) {
     int randomInt = Random.Range(1, atlasLoader.atlasCount());
     // probably check if this int isn't already used to avoid duplicates
     Sprite ball = atlasLoader.getAtlas("monster-" + randomInt);
     // Assign this ball to your monster
  }

}
```

of course it's pseudo code, i didn't test it and you need to replace comments by your own code.